# My cart_item_data isn't showing up in the order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a site that lets a user enter data from a form and have it attached to a product. I was originally using:

```
$cart_item_data ['Entry Link'] = $formUrl;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID,$quantity,0,$cart_item_data);
```

With $formUrl being a link to the form data. Whenever a user made an order, under the product would be 'Entry Link' with the url.

[image]

We later had to add variations to the product so the line looked like:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID,$quantity,$typeID,$cart_item_data);
```

With $typeID being the variation ID. Once I added the $typeID, only the variation showed up on the order in the backend and not the 'Entry Link'.

[image]

If I reset $typeID to '0', the entry link shows up when an order is made. I also tried using the variation id in place of the product id but was still getting the same issue. I looked at the documentation and it should be working.

I need both the variation and the 'Entry Link' to be entered and visible from the backend.

---

This was the part requested by Vincenzo Di Gaetano in the comments

```
$formUrl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_entries&view=entry&id='.$formID.'&lid='.$entryID;
$cart_item_data['Entry Link'] = $formUrl;
$variationAttributes['Per'] = 1000;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID,$quantity,$typeID,$variationAttributes,$cart_item_data);
```

I added variationAttributes to it with 'Per' lining up with the attribute name, '1000' represents the value of that attribute. I hardcoded it in for testing. When I echo just the $formUrl, it does return the correct url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting only 4 arguments **instead of 5** for the `add_to_cart` method of the `WC_Cart` class.

Try replacing this:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $productID, $quantity, $typeID, $cart_item_data );
```

with:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $productID, $quantity, $typeID, $variation, $cart_item_data );
```

Here is an example of how to add a variation to the cart:

- [WordPress WooCommerce - Add a variable product to cart using the WC_Cart class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802172/wordpress-woocommerce-add-a-variable-product-to-cart-using-the-wc-cart-class)

This will not be enough to display the cart item data as the meta of the order item.

Based on this question [Save and display product custom meta on WooCommerce orders and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025782/save-and-display-product-custom-meta-on-woocommerce-orders-and-emails) **you will need to save the value as a order item meta data**:

```
// save the cart item data as custom order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_cart_item_data_as_order_item_meta_data', 20, 4 );
function save_cart_item_data_as_order_item_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $values['Entry Link'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Entry Link'), $values['Entry Link'] );
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I had previously tried that (I should have mentioned that) and it still resulted in the same outcome

Comment: Can you show your full code when adding the product variation to the cart?

Comment: I added it to the end of my original post

Comment: YAY! This works perfectly! Thank you so much :) this has been a huge issue all week! You're a life saver